# Выкусить из статического HTML script

Tags: javascript, php, регулярные-выражения, phpstorm, google-adsense

Есть сайт со множеством статических html страниц (более 10к), в которых человек вставил script коды на google adsense. Делал это он руками, и одного типа кода нет, много разных вхождений, при том он внутри использовал различные:  пример

```html
            <script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-4537875350391092";
/* 2011 Media - Leaderboard */
google_ad_slot = "8974455633";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
            </script>
```

или

```html
            <script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-4537875350391092";
/* 160x600, yellow pages ad right side */
google_ad_slot = "3740828024";
google_ad_width = 160;
google_ad_height = 600;
//-->
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript"
 src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
            </script>
```

Единственно что их объединяет это ca-pub-4537875350391092

Помогите выкусить все это регуляркой, я работаю в phpstorm, там нет флаговых значений :(
Я так понимаю нужно найти ближайшее открытие скрипта до ca-pub-4537875350391092 и ближайшее закрытие после....
При всем этом могут быть переходы на другие строки и т.п.

Comment: выкусить)) `10к статических html страниц`, лул? Может лучше сразу delete нажать и фреймворк для себя open?

Comment: Вадим, спасибо за совет, если была такая возможность - я бы с радостью так и сделал. Изначальный код писался в 98году, в Netscape Composer, но задача стоит сохранить то что было.

Answer (score 0):

Проверь такой регэксп:

`/(.*?)(<script[^>]+>.+?ca-pub-4537875350391092.+?<\/script>)(.*)/s`

[Ссылка на тестер](https://regex101.com/r/GS4ZAJ/1)

Но, если честно, я бы посоветовал набросать небольшой скрипт на `Perl`. По сути там только обход дерева каталогов и обработка файлов по типу. Элементарные вещи, часть из которых можно просто копипастить из ресурсов Интернета.

Comment: Спасибо, работает в вашем примере, но у меня нет возможности добавить флаг /s в phpstorm

Comment: `Perl`'ом пользуетесь?

Comment: Perl'ом по необходимости, не писал уже наверное лет 10

Comment: Вот этот вопрос как раз таки Perl'ом и решается наиболее оперативно. Как я писал выше - скрипт будет элементарнейшим.

Comment: возможно как-то связаться с вами? телега @DeepZip